# Breaking if __name__ when a condition is not met

Tags: python, loops, error-handling, break

I am using

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

to run my defined functions.

However as an error catching measure I am trying to implement a way to ensure that file paths have been entered correctly into the .bat file my script is ran from, the file names are passed in as arguments.

What I am doing is defining a function to define whether certain arguments are "valid", things such as

```
.endswith("\\")
```

or

```
.endswith(".txt")
```

however because they are within an  `if` block (`if __name__` == "**main**"`) I am struggling to work out how to stop the script there.

I basically want to apply my validation function to all the arguments and if any return `False` then to stop the `__main__` function and show an error message in such a way:

```
print len(invalid_args), " arguments are invalid, please check input"
```

However using a `break` here is showing as `"Break is outside of loop"` in pycharm.

How can I stop the rest of my script running if validation returns `False` and it is all contained in the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block?

Here is a representation of my code, but without the unnecessary detail:

```
def clean():
    do_something()

def merge():
    do_something_else()

def valid()
    if valid:
        return True
    if not valid:
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not valid():
        "Stop script here" # This is the part I don't know how to do
    if valid():
        try:
            clear()
        except Exception a e:
            print e + "Something Went Wrong"
        try:
            merge()
        except Exception as e:
            print e + "Something Went Wrong"
```

Comment: Please add the code that you have written, will always fetch better answers.

Comment: `__main__` is not a function; it's just the name of the module the code is executing in. If you want to "break" from that portion of code, you probably just want to call `sys.exit()`.

Comment: I understand that I got the definition of loop wrong. However I think my code, in this instance, isn't important, what my code actually does shouldn't change how I prevent it from running, surely. I'm just looking for clarification of the 2 downvotes? (I'm not disputing the downvotes, just wanting some clarification to make future questions better)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`break`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) is used to break out of a loop (as PyCharm has told you).

Instead you could have the following code which will run your tests and if true not allow the rest of the content to proceed.

```
# Your code ...

def some_function():
    # Something function that runs your tests
    # If your tests fail then return True, otherwise return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if some_function():
        print("Sorry but your .bat file must be broken!")
    else:
        # Run the rest of your code happily.
```

You could even [raise an Exception](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions) as opposed to just printing a message.

Answer (score 4):

`if` is **not** a *"loop"*. You can only `break` from `for` or `while` (which *are* loops). To stop the program outside of a loop, you have a few options:

1. `raise` an error;
2. `sys.exit` the whole program; or
3. guard the rest of the code with another `if`.

For example:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    valid_args, invalid_args = process(args)
    if invalid_args:
        # raise error or exit
    # rest of code
```

or:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    valid_args, invalid_args = process(args)
    if invalid_args:
        # print warning
    else:
        # rest of code
```

Within a function, you can also `return`:

```
def main():
    valid_args, invalid_args = process(args)
    if invalid_args:
        return
    # rest of code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Move all of your logic under `if __name__ == "__main__"` into a separate function, and replace your `if __name__ == "__main__"` block with just

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    doMySetupStuff()
```

Inside your `doMySetupStuff` function, you can check the arguments and `return` if you find any of them are not valid.